# Release stage shows succeeded but pipeline triggered by agent job inside the stage has error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm looking for a way to set the Azure Devops Release stage to failed if an agent job inside it has failed.  The agent job is a build trigger which starts a pipeline. The pipeline fails but the release stage shows succeeded. The only way I know to find the failure is to always check the pipeline run which is additional step.

Comment: There's no way to synchronously run a pipeline and wait for its results; you'd have to write special logic to poll the REST APIs and monitor for a condition. If you provide more detail on your objective (i.e. what Pipeline A and Pipeline B are doing and why A needs to run B, then wait for B to finish), someone can likely provide you more targeted guidance on how to redesign things to avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: Hi Tammy, and welcome to SO. It is not easy to make a parent pipeline wait for a child pipeline; we've implemented a solution where we use the [Azure Devops REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/) to queue the child pipeline, and then poll to check its status until it has finished. To avoid tying up two agents, we've got a [Logic App](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) doing the polling, called from an [agentless Invoke REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api) task.